# sIFR div appears about 40px to the right of where it should be

Tags: sifr, sifr3

When I turn javascript off, the divs containing my text appear exactly where I want them to be. When I turn javascript on and sIFR appears, the sIFR text in those divs appears about 40px to the right of where I want it to be. I can't use the sIFR-config CSS to force the sIFR div back to the right I can crop into the sIFR text inside the div, but I can't shift it back to the left where it ought to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/sample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I had "text-indent" in my regular text's CSS. sIFR interpreted this as indent everything--hence the shift. I deleted "text-indent" and am good again--I still do have it in my sIFR congfig CSS to indent the first line in the paragraph and it's fine there. (So, to indent in the non-sIFR text, I used

tags which sIFR ignores.)

Comment: ...and I &#160; to indent my non-sIFR text.